# Parse Error - Could Not Load Type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've been experiencing this issue on my Web App. The line throwing the error is:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="foo.aspx.vb" Inherits="foo"  %>
```

Things to note:

1. This was a working web application on .NET 2.0. I wanted to migrate it to .NET 4.0.
2. The codebehind file exists.
3. The `Partial` class in the `Inherits` attribute exists.
4. The .dll's are updated in the bin\ of the project and in the bin\ of wwwroot.

I have been to multiple sites and similar questions here in StackOverflow, but the solution suggested are always to check the items in the list above.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your `Inherits` attribute value in below line

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="foo.aspx.vb" Inherits="foo"  %>
```

Inherit attribute contains the full namespace path. So go to your code behind file and check the namespace in which `foo` class exists. It may be exists in your project namespace. Like if your project name is MyProject then it should be something like this `MyProject.foo`

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="foo.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyProject.foo"  %>
```

Comment: This somewhat helped me solved the issue. I tried adding the namespace and then changing the codebehind to codefile. VS then displayed a warning about a context not found. I then removed the namespace in the Inherits attribute and  the page worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Go to **IIS**:

Change your web application pool framerwork from version .NET `2.0` to `4.0`

Comment: The application pool I'm currently using is using 4.0.